# List Of Images from Same Server

Tags: java, android

I am reading the List of Images from same Server, but Image Names are different.

```
for(int i=0;i<moviesL.size();i++)
{
    try
    {
        lName.add(moviesL.get(i).getMovieName());
        URL url = new URL(moviesL.get(i).getImageUrl());
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis));
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It is taking too much time to load.

is there any alternate  this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the downloading multithreaded:

First you have to create a Thread class which downloads the image and stores it in the list of images.

```
class GetImageThread extends Thread {

    URL url;
    LinkedList<Bitmap> images;

    public GetImageThread(URL url, LinkedList<Bitmap> images) {
        this.url = url;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public void run() {
    try {
        URLConnection conn = this.url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        this.images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you start a thread for each movie in the main program:

```
LinkedList<GetImageThread> threads = new LinkedList<GetImageThread>();
for(int i=0;i<moviesL.size();i++) {
    GetImageThread thread = new GetImageThread(moviesL.getImageURL(), images);
    threads.add(thread);
    thread.start();
}
```

Then you have to wait for all threads to be finished.

```
for(GetImageThread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

And one last tip in the end:
It is always better to use the iterator loop instead of the int loop.

```
for(Movie movie : movies)
```

instead of

```
for(int i=0; i<movies.size(); i++)
```